# Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException Element 'link': This element is not expected

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.4

All Magento product pages were working properly last week. Now I check that all product pages through exceptions.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'link': This element is not expected.
Line: 1896


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'link': This element is not expected.
Line: 1896
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that somewhere in your XML layout files you have element `<link/>`, which is not allowed. You can search for all occurrences of '`<link`' in your /app folder (in *.xml files). If it happens only with product pages, check all `catalog_product_view.xml` files

If you can't find it and if your version below 2.3.4, then it is possible that you have entered  element in admin in XML Layout update field somewhere (Category, CMS Page, etc.), in this case you'll only get error on that page / category. So in your case it should be product pages layout updates